# Pass sequence to a bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm looking for a way to pass an arbitrary sequence of numbers to a bash script. I know about `seq`. However, the key word here is *arbitrary*. For example:

```
$ ./do_foo 2,4,5
```

Should perform something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {2,4,5}; do
    foo $i
done
```

And, of course:

```
$ ./do_foo 2..5
```

Should also be possible and perform something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {2..5}; do
    foo $i
done
```

Comment: Why don't you pipe the sequence (generated by `seq` or whatever other program) in to the script (`seq 2 5` |  your_script` ?

Comment: @Anthon That's more or less what I do today (run the loop outside the script), but wanted to see if something a bit more elegant and less verbose was possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass them as parameters:

```
#! /bin/sh
for i in "$@"; do
    foo "$i"
done
```

Then:

```
./do_foo 2 4 5
```

Comment: This covers only part of the problem. You can't do 2..5 this way.

Comment: Sure you can: `./do_foo {2..5}`.

Comment: Oh, I haven't tried it that way! Doh!

Comment: @kos My actual script is a lot more complicated, of course, so I have a few shifts while loading other parameters and then treat the remainder $@ as the sequence.

Comment: @kos Yes, I kinda agree with you. But you can do `do_foo {2,4,5}` as well, which I prefer because it makes usage more consistent.